LSTM classifier sets the same label for all observations
I have time series data of shape 2487, 14(2487 observation and 14 variables). I turned it into tensor 2487, 30, 14 (each observation now comes with its 29 previous observations) to put it in LSTM.
Target is integer of values 0, 1 or 2, because I have 3 classes.
I splitted data into 1987 for train set and 500 for test.
Then I tried to build this net using keras:
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(LSTM(units = 256, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (30, 14)))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.1))
classifier.add(LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences = True))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.1))
classifier.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.1))
classifier.add(LSTM(units = 50))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.1))
classifier.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))
classifier.compile(optimizer=Adam(0.0001),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',              
              metrics=['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 5, batch_size = 100)

But after training, the network produces the same result for all observations in the test set(it sets label "1" for all observations.).
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test.squeeze(axis = 1), y_pred))

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00       179
           1       0.38      1.00      0.55       188
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00       133

    accuracy                           0.38       500
   macro avg       0.13      0.33      0.18       500
weighted avg       0.14      0.38      0.21       500

Here are also the probabilities:
array([[0.35958683, 0.43391982, 0.2064934 ],
       [0.36041895, 0.4336537 , 0.20592736],
       [0.36108494, 0.43334576, 0.20556921],
       ...,
       [0.34858602, 0.4287147 , 0.22269933],
       [0.3492322 , 0.4284182 , 0.22234963],
       [0.3500768 , 0.4280075 , 0.2219157 ]], dtype=float32)

It looks like my network can't classify my data well. But I still feel like I'm doing something wrong. Maybe there's something wrong with the loss or activation function, or maybe it's a metric issue? I am not very experienced with neural networks and will be glad for any help.

You're only training for 100 steps in total. You need to train for much longer. Also remove things like Dropout when you are not overfitting.

@xdurch0 Thank you so much! It really helped. Can I ask about parameters of .compile()? Did I do everything right? Or I better use other metrics or loss? And what should I use if my target is one-hot encoded? I tried OH at first with categorical crossentropy but I didn't succeed.
